# Bounded and closed but not compact in rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm sorry if topic repeated. I solved this problem. And I want to know is my solution true?

Regard $\mathbb{Q}$, the set of all rational numbers, as a metric space, with $d(p,q)=|p-q|$.

Let $E=\{p\in \mathbb{Q}: 2<p^2<3\}$. Show that $E$ is closed and bounded in $\mathbb{Q}$, but $E$ is not compact. Is $E$ open in $\mathbb{Q}$?

**Proof:**
**Boundness:** It easy to check that $E$ is bounded. Because $E\subset B_2(0)=\{z\in \mathbb{Q}:d(z,0)<2\}$ - open ball in $\mathbb{Q}$.

**Closed:** Also $E$ is closed because $E^c=\{p\in \mathbb{Q}: p^2<2\quad  \text{or} \quad p^2>3 \}$ is open set. Because if $z\in E^c$ then $z\in \mathbb{Q}\cap \{z: z^2<2\}$ or $z\in \mathbb{Q}\cap \{z: z^2>3\}$. And for both cases $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $(z+1/n)^2<2$ or $(z-1/n)^2>3$ because both inequalities are solvable for large $n$. Taking $n$ so large we got $N_{1/n}(z)\subset E^c$ where $N_{1/n}(z)=\{q\in \mathbb{Q}: d(q,z)<1/n\}$. So $E^c$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$. Therefore $E$ is closed in $\mathbb{Q}$.

**Compactness:** We'll prove that $E$ is not compact in $\mathbb{Q}$. It means that exists some open cover of $E$ which contains no finite subcover. Let $$G_n=\{\mathbb{Q}\cap [-\sqrt{3}, -\sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{n}]\}\cup \{\mathbb{Q} \cap [\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}-\frac{1}{n}]\}$$ for $n\geqslant 4$. It's easy to verify that $\{G_n\}$ is an open of $E$. But it contains no finite subcover. Therefore, $E$ is not compact in $\mathbb{Q}$.

**Openess:** Set $E$ is open. If $z\in E$ then $z\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $2<z^2<3$. Then exists $n$ so large s.t. $2<(z-1/n)^2<(z+1/n)^2<3$. Hence $N_{1/n}(z)\subset E$.

Comment: I think the only problem is in proving  the closed part, and it is  easily fixed. For example when $z$ is a bit greater than $-\sqrt{2}$ we don't want to add $1/n$.

Comment: Why we can't to add $1/n$?

Comment: I don't see any problem in closed part. Can you point more exactly?

Comment: We can certainly add $1/n$. But (for $z$ negative, a bit bigger than $-\sqrt{2}$) we need to make sure that the entire ball is in the set. So we want to make sure that $(z-1/n)^2\lt 2$.

Comment: You could also verify compactness by appealing the fact that your set has not hope of being complete.

Comment: Dear André Nicolas. I thought about you remark. $(z-1/n)^2<2$ always has solution for large $n$. Example for $n>\frac{1-2z}{2-z^2}$ where $z<0$. Am I true?

Comment: This looks fine.

Answer (score 6):

In general, a metric space is compact iff it is complete and totally bounded. So it suffices to show that $E$ is not complete (considered as a subspace of $\mathbb Q$).

Since $\sup E=\sqrt 3$, $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, and $E$ contains every rational number $p$ with $\sqrt2<p<\sqrt3$, we can construct a sequence $\{p_n\}$ of elements in $E$ such that $\sqrt 3 -p_n<\frac1n$ for each $n$. Therefore $p_n\to\sqrt3$ (in $\mathbb R$), so in the induced metric on $\mathbb Q$, $\{p_n\}$ is still a Cauchy sequence. But $\{p_n\}$ has no limit in $E$, so $E$ is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I also have one interesting question.

We know that: A set $K$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact iff $K$ is closed and bounded.

But this example shows that our set $E$ is closed and bounded but NOT compact. It's really confused me. I show that $E$ is not compact. Where is problem?
It must be compact because $E=\{p\in \mathbb{Q}:2<p^2<3\}\subset \mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{R^1}$.

Can anyone exlain me this paradox?

I would be thankful.

Comment: $E$ is not closed in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Our set $E$ is bounded in $\mathbb{Q}$ (also in $\mathbb{R}$) and set $E$ is closed in $\mathbb{Q}$ (but NOT closed in $\mathbb{R}$). Hence by Heine-Borel theorem the set $E$ is NOT compact in $R$. Also we showed that $E$ is NOT compact in $\mathbb{Q}$. Am I true?